# Google Maps resize: maptype control button css style disappears

Tags: css, google-maps, settimeout

i have a map on my page with **maptype** control button. When initializing the map i add a css style(highlighting the current active map type, like "Map" or "Satellite")to the button.

When **resized**, the map kind of reloads and the button css disappears, so i have to wait for the resize to end and reapply css style on the button.

In the end it just looks weird, because the map loads and the button has default color, after 2 seconds (i use **settimeout**) the button is applied the css again. How can this be done so the button gets the css before map loads and also keep that css.

Should i use a callback here and would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls), few rules are necessary to create your own custom control. The following are the guidelines which also acts as best practice:

> - Define appropriate CSS for the control element(s) to display.
> - Handle interaction with the user or the map through event handlers for either map property changes or user events (for example, `click` events).
> - Create a  element to hold the control and add this element to the Map's controls property.

To know more about these concerns, please go through the discussion and sample codes in the given documentation primarily in the following:

- Drawing Custom Controls
- Handling Events from Custom Controls
- Positioning Custom Controls
- A Custom Control Example
- Adding State to Controls

Comment: yes, thanks, i ended up using my own custom control because i guess Google does not want their default controls to be messed around with.